# parsing JSON to class and transforming on-the-fly

Tags: apex, json

I have an @RestResource listening for a JSON string to be passed to me.  I then use a JSON2Apex class to parse the JSON into a usable format.  However, I receive dates in "seconds", an example of which is "start_date=1424915617" which once I run through DateTime.newInstance(0).addSeconds(start_date) it correctly shows Feb 25 @ 1:53pm...

However, I have to do that after the fact using a second variable `started_at_dt`... I have to have:

```
global class JSON2Apex {
    global Integer started_at;
    global DateTime started_at_dt {
       get {
            if (started_at_dt == null && started_at != null)
                started_at_dt = DateTime.newInstance(0).addSeconds(started_at);
            return started_at_dt;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Is there a way that as part of the setting process, I could transform from the `Integer` value to the `DateTime` value without having to duplicate the variables?

```
global class JSON2Apex {
    global DateTime started_at; // could i use a {get;set;}?  is there another way to do this?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apex serialize/deserialize to Type doesn't have complete control on how data types gets serialized or deserialized.

Comment: I was thinking there may be a way using the set side of { get; set; } but with my limited experience with setters, I don't know if it's possible.  I certainly didn't stumble into a working solution using that method...